# Raster Reprojection - request raster on different projection

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver, wms

Im trying to make a WMS Request using OpenLayers3, with a OSM Base map (EPSG:3857).
The raster data on geoserver is on EPSG:32629.

Somehow(?!) my setup worked fine till recently.
The raster image correctly appeared on the map even with different projections.

After the update to 2.15.2 my layers are no longer displayed.
I traced the problem to a reprojection issue but couldn't quite figure it out.

my request is basically:

```html
var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        ratio: 1,
        url: 'http://mygeo/geoserver/ws/wms',
        params: {
            'FORMAT': 'image/png',
            'VERSION': '1.1.1',
            "LAYERS": 'ws:myraster'
        }
    })
});
```

i've tried setting the 'SRS' parameter on the request (adding it to the params) but OL forces the 3857.

On the geoserver, the raster layer is configured with both native and declared SRS with 32629 and "Force Declared".

Any Thoughts that might help ?

Regards

Comment: OpenLayers won't use WIDTH, HEIGHT, BBOX, CRS or SRS specified in params.  https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/apidoc/ol.source.ImageWMS.html
**WIDTH, HEIGHT, BBOX and CRS (SRS for WMS version < 1.3.0) will be set dynamically**.  To set the projection of the WMS request set the projection option in ol.source.ImageWMS

Comment: added the <code>projection: 'EPSG:32629',</code> still wont work. how must the layer be configured at geoserver? can it be at its original projection (32629)?

Comment: well, i got it to work. 

ive checked (again) the documentation and had a go, step by step.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/raster-reprojection.html

the error was i didnt included the 32629 projection in proj4js using "proj4.defs(...)".